# getStore(); undefined Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, store

I have 2 stores with loaded data.

**First store:**

```
Ext.define('Connecting.store.Groups', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Connecting.model.groupModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'Connecting.model.groupModel',
        storeId: 'Groups',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://localhost/php/getGroups.php',
            reader: {

                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Second store:**

```
Ext.define('Connecting.store.Secondgroups', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Connecting.model.Secondgroup',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'Connecting.model.Secondgroup',
        storeId: 'Secondgroup',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://localhost/php/getSecondGroup.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The first store works;

```
 var store = Ext.getStore('Groups');
 console.log(store);
```

But when I change the `storeId` to '`Secondgroup`'(in getStore) my `console.log` will give me an `'undefined'`..

I can't seem the find the problem.. any suggestions in what direction I have to look?

PS. I am using Sencha Architect, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Dumb question... but are you sure the second store is loaded AND instantiated?

Comment: I uses Architect to create the store, and i can see that it's fully loaded with records. I am not really sure if its instantiated, but so far as i know i have never did that before..or maybe i did it without knowing it.

Comment: did you drop an 's' off the "Secondgroup" or is that a typo??

Comment: Yeah i noticed that too, i changed it so that all(store, model and storeId) has the same name now (Secondgroups) but it still gets me an undefined..

Comment: Did you add the store to the Ext.application? For example, Ext.application({ name: 'MyApp', models: ['model1', 'model2'], stores: ['Groups', 'Secondgroup'] });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sencha Touch actually uses what you used in the define.

For the second group, try using Ext.getStore('Secondgroups'); and this should work for you.

Comment: I've found the solution! I defined the store but somehow it wasnt created yet while my first store was. The only thing i had to do was: Ext.create('Connecting.store.Secondgroups', {

             

            }); and then i used  var store = Ext.getStore('Secondgroups');

After that the 'undefined' was gone and i could fill my store :)